# ASP.NET MVC Knockout Binding Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js, mvc-editor-templates

I am working with Mvc4/bootstrap 3.2 and knockout 3.2. Problem Is I have a form that has a. textbox and button, on button click I pass textbox value to controller. After receiving data from controller binding viewModel with table. But neither data is not updated in table nor the mvc Model updated. I have check that while submitting the data.

ViewModel : I have Tried ViewMoel in two ways

```
var SibviewModel=null;
    $(function () {
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        SibviewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
        ko.applyBindings(SibviewModel);
    });

function GetMatchingSibling(_Id) {
        var url = "/Home/GetStudentSiblingDetails/?Id=" + _Id;
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                try {
                    $(data.data).each(function (index, element) {
                        SibviewModel.SibviewModel.push(element);
                    });
                    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

                } catch (e) {
                    $(".alert-dismissable")
                    .alert('show')
                    .addClass("alert-danger")
                    .append("<h3>"+e+"</h3>");

                }
                finally {
                    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                }


            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + data.error);
                $("#myModal").modal('hide');
            }
        });
    }
```

Then I wrote MVC Razor view

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: lookupCollection">
            @foreach (var item in Model.LinkedSiblings)
            {
                string dobval = "";
                if (Model.DOB.HasValue)
                {
                    dobval = Model.DOB.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                }

                @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.PhoneNo, new { @Name = "LinkedSiblings[" + item.DynamicControlId + "].PhoneNo", @Value = item.PhoneNo, data_bind = "value: PhoneNo" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Email, new { @Name = "LinkedSiblings[" + item.DynamicControlId + "].Email", @Value = "santokh.hcl@hmail.com", data_bind = "value: Email" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => dobval, new { @Name = "LinkedSiblings[" + item.DynamicControlId + "].DOB", @Value = dobval, data_bind = "value: DOB" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.LastName, new { @Name = "LinkedSiblings[" + item.DynamicControlId + "].LastName", @Value = item.LastName, data_bind = "value: LastName" })
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: StudentId">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.StudentId, new { style = "max-width:100px;", @Name = "LinkedSiblings[" + item.DynamicControlId + "].StudentId", @Value = item.StudentId, data_bind = "value: StudentId" })
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.AdmissionId, new { style = "max-width:100px;", @Name = "LinkedSiblings[" + item.DynamicControlId + "].AdmissionId", @Value = item.AdmissionId, data_bind = "value: AdmissionId" })
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.FirstName, new { style = "max-width:100px;", @Name = "LinkedSiblings[" + item.DynamicControlId + "].FirstName", @Value = item.FirstName, data_bind = "value: FirstName" })
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.ClassId, new { style = "max-width:100px;", @Name = "LinkedSiblings[" + item.DynamicControlId + "].ClassId", @Value = item.ClassId, data_bind = "value: ClassId" })
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
            @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.LinkedSiblings)
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Neither the View is updated with the Values not the Values Received on Controller Method when submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in calling ko.applyBindings in your AJAX callback:

```
try {
    $(data.data).each(function (index, element) {
        SibviewModel.SibviewModel.push(element);
    });
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
```

First problem is that you are passing variable `viewModel` which is not declared (I can't see the declaration) or contains old data (you updated data in `SibviewModel.SibviewModel`)

Second problem is that you should not call `ko.applyBindings`. It will throw an exception in knockout 3.x - you cannot bind two viewModels to the same element. Also it is misunderstanding of the basic concept of knockout.js and data-binding. If you modify the model, changes are propagated automatically to the view, you do not have to call any function... `ko.applyBindings` is just used for initialization of a new binding. That is not your case, you have an existing binding and you just want to update the model.

Maybe there might be another mistakes, I didn't check the whole code...

BTW you have there also a performance issue, check this article - http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

Comment: Thanks A lot for your response. Actually had declared the Viewmodel but I had not added the full code here. I would made the recommended changes, But Will it be reflected when i shall submit the form I mean (Will list be passed to controller action).

Answer (score 0):

```
  var viewModel = {
        lookupCollection: ko.observableArray()
    };
    var SibviewModel=null;
    $(function () {
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        SibviewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
        ko.applyBindings(SibviewModel);
    });

    function GetMatchingSibling(_Id) {
        var url = "/Home/GetStudentSiblingDetails/?Id=" + _Id;
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                try {
                    $(data.data).each(function (index, element) {
                        SibviewModel.LinkedSiblings.push(element);
                    });
                    ko.applyBindings(LinkedSiblings);

                } catch (e) {
                    $(".alert-dismissable")
                    .alert('open')
                    .removeClass('alert-warning')
                    .addClass("alert-danger")
                    .append("<h3>"+e+"</h3>");   
                }
                finally {
                    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                }
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + data.error);
                $("#myModal").modal('hide');
            }
        });
    }
```

:Jookyn . I have attached full JS code that I have used for updating List. In Place of Lookup Collection I have been using "LinkedSiblings" for foreach loop on table